# Using Raspberry Pi to Receive Float from Arduino using NRF24L01

Tags: arduino, dht22, nrf24l01

Good day. I've been learning on how to transfer data from Arduino to Raspberry Pi wirelessly using NRF24L01 based on the following reference:
[Raspberry Pi 3 Tutorial 14 – Wireless Pi to Arduino Communication with NRF24L01+](http://invent.module143.com/daskal_tutorial/raspberry-pi-3-wireless-pi-to-arduino-communication-with-nrf24l01/).

The reason why I want to do this is to log temperature and humidity data wirelessly using DHT22 sensors.

The Arduino code is shown below:

```
//SendReceive.ino

#include<SPI.h>
#include<RF24.h>

// CE, CSN pins
RF24 radio(9, 10);

void setup(void){
    while(!Serial);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    radio.begin();
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    radio.setChannel(0x76);
    radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL);
    const uint64_t pipe = (0xE8E8F0F0E1LL);
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);

    radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
    radio.powerUp();

}

void loop(void){
    radio.startListening();
    Serial.println("Starting loop. Radio on.");
    char receivedMessage[32] = {0};
    if(radio.available()){
        radio.read(receivedMessage, sizeof(receivedMessage));
        Serial.println(receivedMessage);
        Serial.println("Turning off the radio.");
        radio.stopListening();

        String stringMessage(receivedMessage);

        if(stringMessage == "GETSTRING"){
            Serial.println("Looks like they want a string!");
            const char text[] = "Yo wassup, haha";
            radio.write(text, sizeof(text));
            Serial.println("We sent our message.");
        }
    }
    delay(100);

}
```

Meanwhile, the Raspberry Pi code is shown below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0])
radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
# radio.startListening()

message = list("GETSTRING")
while len(message) &lt; 32:
    message.append(0)

while(1):
    start = time.time()
    radio.write(message)
    print("Sent the message: {}".format(message))
    radio.startListening()

    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1 / 100)
        if time.time() - start &gt; 2:
            print("Timed out.")
            break

    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))

    print("Translating the receivedMessage into unicode characters")
    string = ""
    for n in receivedMessage:
        # Decode into standard unicode set
        if (n &gt;= 32 and n &lt;= 126):
            string += chr(n)
    print("Out received message decodes to: {}".format(string))

    radio.stopListening()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Based on the Arduino code above, the code that shows the data that is transmitted is shown below:

```
const char text[] = "Yo wassup, haha";
```

Based on the Raspberry code above, the codes that decode the received data from Arduino are shown below:

```
for n in receivedMessage:
    # Decode into standard unicode set
    if (n &gt;= 32 and n &lt;= 126):
        string += chr(n)
```

However, these decoding code only works if I transmit string or integer from Arduino to Raspberry Pi. It doesn't work if I transmit float. Since DHT22 records temperature and humidity up until 1 decimal point, it is required for me to transmit float. Can anyone here please teach me how to decode the float values?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is really an Arduino question, you would probably get better answer from [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com). To covert float to str in Arduino, you will need `dtostrf()` function, this [article](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-float-vars) may be provide an example on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I see. All this time I thought it is Raspberry Pi's part because I think I should decode the string to float in the Raspberry Pi side.

I will ask the same question in Arduino Stack Exchange. Thank you again.